# Greasemonkey script to reload the page every minute

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, reload

How to reload a page every 60 seconds?

My attempt:

```
setTimeout (location.reload, 1 * 60 * 60);
```

I'm not sure what those numbers mean, or how to adapt them to reload after 60 seconds only.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
setTimeout(function(){ location.reload(); }, 60*1000);
```

You have to pass a full function as first argument, and second is the time in millisecond. So in your case, 60 * 1000

Comment: So, would 5 seconds be 5 * 1000?

Comment: Yes it would! It is the delay in milliseconds. So 5000 is 5 seconds

Comment: for 300 seconds, can I simply do `300*1000`? (I'm confused by the documentation)

Comment: Yes you can. As I said, it's the time in milliseconds

Answer (score 10):

You may give a function name, since it is a callable, however, `location.reload` is a method of the `location` object. It is callable, but when it is executed by the timer, the `this` context will not be the location object. This fact leads to an error.

The solutions are:
Write a simple anonymous function as a wrapper as already described in the accepted answer or
create a bound function of the reload method with `location` as its `this` context:

```
setTimeout(location.reload.bind(location), 60000);
```

Comment: I would favorite this answer if I could. That particular glitch has bugged me for a long time, and though I've worked around it, it's great to connect the dots and figure out why it happened.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at [a documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.setTimeout) might help you. The parameters to the setTimeout function are the action which is performed and the number of milliseconds until this happens. `1 * 60 * 60` is 3600ms or 3.6 seconds. A timespan of 60 seconds would be 60000.